# Annotations on model properties in SwaggerUI

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, nswag

I have built a ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web API, and I am interested in auto-generating documentation for my clients.  I've followed the very simple instructions found here: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to install either NSwag or Swashbuckle in my project and in both cases I can see documentation for my APIs, but there are no descriptions on the model properties.

Java seems to have an @ApiModelProperty annotation for this, but I don't see a similar attribute in .Net.  Is it possible to add descriptions for Model properties in either of these swagger implementations, that would show up in Schema section in the Swagger UI?

Comment: I'm curious why someone would vote to close this question.  Following the guidelines, this question is not a duplicate of a similar question, it is specific and not vague (can I annotate model properties in the Swagger UI or not; if so how?), and it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard xml doc summary works for me.

```
public class TokenRefreshRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The JWT access token
    /// </summary>
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The refresh token that was sent via the new token endpoint or the last refresh.
    /// </summary>
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

Shows on the swagger page as;

[image]

You can add limited markdown as well but I can't seem to find the link.

Comment: Thank you, I got that to work in both NSwag and Swagger.